# C# Selenium can't find button

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

```
<form name="loginForm" ng-submit="login()" autocomplete="off" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
<button type="submit" class="icon-login" ng-disabled="!loginForm.$valid" disabled="enabled"></button>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username / Email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" required="" ng-model="credentials.username" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" required="" ng-model="credentials.password" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
</form>
```

I tried:

```
  IWebElement button = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("icon-login"));
```

But that didn't work and when I took a screenshot it appears that the button is just not visible while it should be...

I tried using a wait until too but that just times out even with a minute on it

edit:

```
IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//form[@name='loginForm']/button[@class='icon-login']")));
```

Tried that but it justs times out, the element does exsist but not clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment update along with the *url* it seems the *Username*, *Password* field and the *Login* button all are within a form. So once you fill up the *Username*, *Password* fields you can straightway invoke the `Submit()` method to login into the website as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@id='username' and @name='username']"))).SendKeys("refactorcoding");
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='password' and @name='password']")).SendKeys("refactorcoding");
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='password' and @name='password']")).Submit();
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the button not the username

Comment: @refactorcoding Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: '{"errorMessage":"Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Connection":"Close","Content-Length":"2","Content-Type":"application/

Comment: @refactorcoding Can you update the question with your current code trials and the error stack trace please?

Comment: @refactorcoding What is the `<button>` all about? Why do you want to click that button?

Comment: to login to the website :)

Comment: @refactorcoding I am still clueless why you need to click on a button when the _username_ and _password_ field is available. Can you share the __url?

Comment: @refactorcoding Checkout my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: that's very nice but how would I do

Comment: <div class="pill-wrap double">
<a ng-click="modalCancel()" class="button pill">No</a>
<a ng-click="modalSuccess()" class="button pill">Yes</a>
</div>

Comment: And press the No button

Comment: @refactorcoding That seem to be a separate question :) Can you raise a new ticket as per your new requirement please?